# jQuery target specific DOM element based on variable

Tags: jquery

EDIT: the reset should be hiding the div and removing the border!

Hi there I'm trying to add a border and show some content based on a variable being counted up and down, I thought .eq(variable) might do the trick but struggling to find an answer - any help would be appreciated

(See //change specific dom item based in pos variable number)

```
var items = $(".owl-item").length
console.log("consultant images: " + items)

var pos = 1;
console.log("pos: " + pos)

function activateBio() {
  //reset
  $(".owl-item").css("border-bottom", "none")
  $(".consultants_bio").css("display", "none")

  //change specific dom item based in pos variable number
  $(".owl-item").eq(pos).css("border-bottom", "4px solid #e28b3a")
  $(".consultants_bio").eq(pos).css("display", "block")
}

// Go to the previous item
$('.owl-prev').click(function() {
  if (pos >= 1 && pos <= items) {
    pos -= 1;
    console.log("pos: " + pos)
    activateBio()
  }
})
// Go to the next item
$('.owl-next').click(function() {
  if (pos >= 0 && pos < items) {
    pos += 1;
    console.log("pos: " + pos)
    activateBio()
  }
})
```

Comment: 1. You're a few lines of code away from a snippet which would make this alot easier to help with. 2. Consider using classes rather than css - cleaner and easier to maintain. 3. Your prev and next handlers could trigger a single function with a +/- flag and make your code slimmer and easier to maintain

Comment: Your comments `// Go to the next item` and `// Go to the previous item` are backwards.

Comment: `.eq(pos)` should work.

Comment: `pos < items` should be `pos < items-2`. The maximum useful value of `pos` is `items-1`.

Comment: Thanks everyone sorted now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use addClass/removeClass to add/remove a class from an element.

Here I have a class called active that has the border. By default as a test I added active to the first element, but using removeClass and referencing anything owl-item with the active class to remove it.

```js
$(".owl-item.active").removeClass("active")

let pos = 1;
$(".owl-item").eq(pos).addClass("active")
```

```css
.active{
  border-bottom:4px solid #e28b3a
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="owl-item active">1</div>
<div class="owl-item ">2</div>
<div class="owl-item">3</div>
```